# Why VC++ compiler gives error on compound operator overloading?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, operator-overloading

I'm trying to learn `C++`. And I have some operator overloading functions like below (I took it from The C++ Programming Language fourth edition, page 76):

```
complex& operator+=(complex z) { re += z.re; im += z.im; return *this; } // add to re and im
// and return the result
complex& operator−=(complex z) { re  -= z.re; im -= z.im; return *this; }
complex& operator*=(complex); // defined out-of-class somewhere
complex& operator/=(complex); // defined out-of-class somewhere
```

The `+=` overloading is working fine, but for `-=` , I got **10** compiler errors:

[image]

If I remove the `=` and just overload `-` operator, it compiles. What is the reason ? I'm wondering what I have done wrong? I have tried several combinations, clear-rebuild the solution,re-start the Visual studio, but they didn't work.

Note: I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and I have installed the [Visual C++ Compiler November 2013 CTP](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41151)

Here is the full class definition:

```
class complex{
     double re, im;
     // representation: two doubles
public:
    complex(double r, double i) :re{ r }, im{ i } {} // construct complex from two scalars
    complex(double r) :re{ r }, im{ 0 } {} // construct complex from one scalar
    complex() :re{ 0 }, im{ 0 } {} // default complex: {0,0}
    double real() const { return re; }
    void real(double d) { re = d; }
    double imag() const { return im; }
    void imag(double d) { im = d; }
    complex& operator+=(complex z) { re += z.re; im += z.im; return *this; } // add to re and im
    // and return the result
    complex& operator−=(complex z) { re  -= z.re; im -= z.im; return *this; }
    complex& operator*=(complex); // defined out-of-class somewhere
    complex& operator/=(complex); // defined out-of-class somewhere
};
```

Comment: As a side note, better make your operators take a `const complex&`. As it is now, when you call an operator the given complex is being copied, which is wasteful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that in token `-=` there are some other symbols (It seems that instead a minus there is some other character)

```
operator−=(
```

Retype token `-=` anew or copy the whole line from my post.:)

```
complex& operator-=(complex z) { re  -= z.re; im -= z.im; return *this; }
```

Comment: anyway it was because of me not the compiler, I copy/pasted the code from .pdf file (because of my laziness). from now on, no more copy/paste :)

Comment: @Selman22  Yes it was clear that there is some typographical symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things:

- Your constructors are OK except for the braces at each initializer. The braces are only for blocks of code after the comma-delimited list of member initializers, like so:

`complex(double r, double i) :re(r), im(i) {}`

- Second, you appear to have some weird characters in the `operator-=` section. It looked OK but wouldn't compile when I pasted it. I just retyped `operator-=` and zip, it worked.

Comment: you are right for the second, but the braces are working fine, I'm not sure but I think they are new in c++11 ?